# Preventing array from adding duplicate element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this piece of code:

```
var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const letter1 = 'B'

for(var i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
    var letter = letters[i]
    if (letter1 === letter) {
        console.log(letter)
        break
    } else {
        letters.push(letter1)
        break
    }
}

console.log(letters)
```

After running this code, I got this result:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
```

But I want this result:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not to allow dupes and then remove them after you finished adding things into this array?

Comment: Check if it's already in the array before pushing to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to check if the value is in the array before pushing it:

```js
if (!letters.includes(letter1)) letters.push(letter1)
```

If you want to remove duplicates from an array, you can convert it to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and back again:

```js
[...new Set(letters)]
```

Alternatively, you could just use a `Set` instead of an array, which is meant for storing unique values:

```js
const letters = new Set(['A', 'B', 'C'])
// Use add instead of push (there is no push method on Set)
letters.add(letter1)
```

---

I'm not sure why you're pushing `letter1` (`'B'`) to the array if you don't want duplicates though.

Comment: `Set` is the way to go

Comment: I wanted to push 'B' to check whether it already exists in the array or not.

Comment: which way is better - computation wise?

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicate(payload) {
    const result = [];

    payload.forEach(function(value) {
        if(result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value)
        }
    })

    return value
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check if array has the element before inserting.

[Array.proptotype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will help

```
if(!extingArray.includes(element)) {
    existingArray.push(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `letters.pop()` to remove any duplicates that might get entered into the end of the array.